# Help me to customize gtk3 theme

Tags: themes, gtk3

I'm trying to make a flat theme, which will look identical for gtk2 and gtk3 apps.
For now, I'm trying to get rid of outlines on toolbars and menubars in gtk3.

This is code from `gtkrc-2.0`, which remove outlines:

```
GtkMenuBar     ::internal-padding     = 0
GtkMenuBar::shadow-type = GTK_SHADOW_NONE
GtkToolbar     ::internal-padding     = 0
GtkToolbar::shadow-type = GTK_SHADOW_NONE
```

I need code which does the same for `gtk-widgets.css`.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I maybe wrong but I don't think gtk3 (which uses css) will have something as convenient. You may have to work your way through the entire gtk-widgets.css file and remove all shadows, gradients, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found by myself after some experiments:

```
    .menubar 
    {
    padding:        0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-width:   0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    }


    .toolbar
    {
    padding:        0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-width:   0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
```